# What is %u in ssh and does it apply only for the directory structure?

Tags: shell-script, sshd

I am going through a sample sshd config file and I found a line saying

```
AuthorizedKeysFile /etc/ssh/%u.authorized_keys
```

I am wondering what %u means here?
It's looking for a file called -  www-user.authorized_keys
The %u should expand to www-user based on the login id I provided. It expands to www-user only when I have a folder
like /home/%u/authorized_keys, then it expands to /home/www-user/authorized_keys.
However, if I give /home/%u/%u.authorized_keys. The file name isn't expanded to 
www-user.authorized_keys. Is this a known issue or bug in openssh? It used to work in openssh version 6.x but it seems not to work on 7.x version. Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 6):

`%u` is not a feature of your shell, it's a *token* specific to the interpretation of the `sshd_config` file.

From `man sshd_config`:

```
TOKENS
     Arguments to some keywords can make use of tokens, which are expanded at
     runtime:

           %%    A literal ‘%’.
           %F    The fingerprint of the CA key.
           %f    The fingerprint of the key or certificate.
           %h    The home directory of the user.
           %i    The key ID in the certificate.
           %K    The base64-encoded CA key.
           %k    The base64-encoded key or certificate for authentication.
           %s    The serial number of the certificate.
           %T    The type of the CA key.
           %t    The key or certificate type.
           %u    The username.
```

So if finds the file by expanding `%u` to the (remote) username.

Similar tokens are used in a number of other contexts such as

- in the [Exec key](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/desktop-entry-spec-latest.html#exec-variables) of a freedesktop Desktop Entry
- as specifiers in a [systemd unit file](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html)

Comment: Does %u only expands for directory structure and not for the file names?

Comment: @tannoyconnect sorry, I don't understand your question

Comment: The authorized key file name is  %u.authorized_keys  will be expanded to the login name concatenated by the username but I believe this doesn't happen in the openssh version 7. But, if I put %u in the path directory structure then it can be expanded accurately i..e /home/%u/authorized_keys then I see it works fine. So, I was asking is  that %u only works with the directory path structure and not with the filename.

Comment: Is there any way to check what value it expands on to during run time - %u? Like any logs to see what it has expanded to?

Comment: @tannoyconnect `%u.authorized_keys` will expand to the logname (username) concatenated with literal string `.authorized_keys`. If you want the user's home directory then use `%h` in place of `%u`.